# How do you Tap to hide keyboard first, then tap again to select cell in Swift?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following extension, which hides the keyboard when ever a tap is registered anywhere in the view.

```
    //Extension to hide the keyboard when tap anywhere
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()  {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

This used in the viewDidLoad() of my ViewController which also is a delegate/datasource to a TableView Controller.

```
 self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
```

The dismissal of the keyboard works perfectly well, **although the behaviour that I am after is for the keyboard to be dismissed first at first tap anywhere on the view/tableview before the user taps again to select a row from the search results in a tableview.**

Currently a tap anywhere is not only dismissing the keyboard but also selecting the cell where the user has tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Add notification observer and Check for keyboard in didselectrow method.

```
var isKeyBoard = false

override func viewDidLoad() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillAppear(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo, 
       isKeyBoard = true
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillDisappear(_ notification: NSNotification) {
   isKeyBoard = false
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       if isKeyBoard {
         self.view.endEditing(true)
         return

       }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay I appreciate your support here, although this seems like a complex solution to a simple task (then again I am new to Swift), are you aware of a gesture recognizer approach perhaps that can be registered with the tableview in order to achieve this as more succinct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just a Normal check you can initialise as

Keyboard is Open That means A TextField Is acting as a First Responder

Now you just simply need to check in didSelect Method here I am Showing you in my collectionView DidSelect Method same as you can do in your Tableview DidSelect

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        /// Check do TF is First Responder 
        /// If yes Just Hide the Keyboard for first time
        if propertySearchTF.isFirstResponder {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return
        }
        /// if TF is not First Responder 
        /// Execution will start from here
        /// DidSelect Code
    }
```

Tested in TableView :

TF Outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTF: UITextField!{
        didSet{
            myTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```

TableView Method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if self.myTF.isFirstResponder {
                self.view.endEditing(true)
                return
            }
            print(selectedKey)
            selectedimage = images[indexPath.row] as UIImage
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the gesture on tableView with `cancelsTouchesInView = true`

```
extension UITableView {

    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()  {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Call from `viewDidLoad()`  `tableView.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()`

Comment: Thanks @Salman I prefer your approach here...although how would my extension code look like (keep in mind that it is placed in an Extensions.swift file), I tried updating my current code to extend UITableview but without any success.

Comment: it is not working :( ... when the VC freshly loads and I tap on the tableview it executes the dismissKeyboard() within the extension and does not allow to select a cell. When the keyboard is present it again executes the dismissKeyboard() function but does not dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: It's call `dismissKeyboard` as per condition but not dismiss keyboard right?

Comment: I have a UISearch element that displays the keyboard, when the tablewiew is refreshed the user will typically tap the tableview to disimiss the keyboard and then tap again to select row.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking, but yeah the function is called dismissKeyboard()